# Como testar uma classe singleton em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, testes, testes-de-unidade

Estou usando require "singleton" para fazer uma determinada classe só poder ser instanciada uma vez. Entretanto, na hora de executar os testes com rspec, recebo o seguinte erro:

> NoMethodError: private method `new' called for MinhaClasse.

Não estou instanciando a classe com `new`, mas sim pegando a referência para o objeto com `MinhaClasse.instance`. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Pode mostrar a parte do código dos seus testes que causam o problema (instancializam a classe com `new`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melhor mostrar com um exemplo:

```
# Obs.: Não foi testado
describe MySingletonClass do
  subject { MySingletonClass.instance }
  describe '#to_s' do
    it 'works' do
      expect(subject.to_s).to be eq(subject.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

Se isso não ajudar, talvez seja uma boa idéa compartilhar os teus testes